# Excel VBA: Highlight textbox value after error occurs - similar

Tags: excel, vba

All,

I have a simple userform with two textboxes.  I'm attempting to trap an error and send the user back to TextBox1 if the entry is > 1,000.  I found code on this site which gets close under the same Title as above.

The code below traps the error and highlights the number >1,000 entered in Textbox1 (without an error message box).  However, if I "uncomment" and enter the

MsgBox ("Value is Greater than 1,000")

after the Cancel = True the error will trap, the msg box displays, but the number greater than 1,000 will not highlight.

I've pulled most of what remains of my hair trying to see why this doesn't work and the example I'm following does.  Help!!

Thanks

Stan

```
Private SkipIT As Boolean

'------------------------------------------------------

Private Sub TextBox1_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    If SkipIT Then Exit Sub

    With Me.TextBox1
        If Val(Me.TextBox1.Value) > 1000 Then
            Cancel = True
            'MsgBox ("Value is Greater than 1,000")  'Will highlight if this line is commented, but no error message box
            .SetFocus
            .SelStart = 0
            .SelLength = Len(.Text)
        End If
    End With
 End Sub

'--------------------------------------------------------------------

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    SkipIT = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Works for me both with or without the MsgBox

Comment: Tim, thanks for trying.  That's my frustration.  I'm running 64 bit Excel 2016 (subscription) on a Dell laptop.  Can you think of any settings that would cause the message box to nix the highlight?

Comment: I don't have any experience with 64-bit Office but I'd be surprised if that's the issue.  Is your form shown modally, or is it non-modal?

Comment: open a new workbook. put the above listed code and try it. there may be something in the existing workbook.  ... you could also put in `debug.print now()` right after `if skipit ...` ... it is just a "flag" to see how many times the sub runs (i use now() because it changes, which makes it easier to see how many times it printed)

Comment: comment out all code in the sub. then add these three lines `Cancel = True` 
   `Me.TextBox1.SelStart = 0`
   `Me.TextBox1.SelLength = 3`

Comment: Gentlemen,   Thanks for your time. I've always opened the form   UserForm1.Show vbModeless, which was not working.  Per Tim's suggestion I dropped the vbModeless and it works!  I can live with that, though are you aware of a way to get the highlight after error to work in vbModeless mode?  Really appreciate your inputs, it got me off of the rocks and back under sail.